# How can I check whether the column data is present in other table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables say Jobs, results, ordered, I have joined 'jobs' and 'results' table (using jobID ) and I need to check the whether the result ID is present in orders tables or not, if present it should print Yes or else no

```
set @sno:=0; SELECT @sno:=@sno+1 Id, j.job_id,gr.name as Group_name, u.name User_name, p.name Project_name, j.version,j.type,vendor,tech, functionality as Algo,words,bits,freq, j.status,r.macroId, CASE WHEN o.macroId IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END Ordered, j.cmd_line,j.submit_date FROM job j JOIN cut_results_vw r ON j.job_id = r.jobId LEFT OUTER JOIN project p ON j.project_id = p.project_id LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON j.user_id = u.user_id LEFT OUTER JOIN groups gr ON j.group_id = gr.group_id LEFT JOIN ordered_cuts o ON r.macroId = o.macroId
```

Comment: Post the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Read on MySQL JOIN, see other examples in stackoverflow about JOIN, and try something, people will not code for you - they will help you

Comment: `set @sno:=0;
SELECT @sno:=@sno+1 Id, j.job_id,gr.name as Group_name,
 u.name User_name, p.name Project_name,
 j.version,j.type,vendor,tech,
 functionality as Algo,words,bits,freq,
 j.status,r.macroId, 
 CASE WHEN o.macroId IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END Ordered,
 j.cmd_line,j.submit_date
  FROM job j 
 JOIN cut_results_vw r ON j.job_id = r.jobId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN project p ON j.project_id = p.project_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON j.user_id = u.user_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN groups gr ON j.group_id = gr.group_id
 LEFT JOIN ordered_cuts o ON r.macroId = o.macroId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select j.*, 
       case when o.resultid is not null 
            then 'yes' 
            else 'no'
       end as present
from jobs j
inner join results r on r.jobid = j.jobid
left outer join orders o on o.resultid = r.resultid
```

Comment: Thanks juergen n peterm, I got bit confused with 'case'

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your actual table schemas, but you can try it this way

```
SELECT j.*, r.*, 
       CASE WHEN o.resultid IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END resultid_is_present
  FROM jobs j JOIN results r
    ON j.jobid = r.jobid LEFT JOIN ordered o
    ON r.resultid = o.resultid
```

To better understand `JOIN`s read

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)